# Greedy subrules in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm working on a parser grammar that should allow trailing expressions without enclosing symbols. The following is a simplified version that evidences the issue:

```
grammar Example;

root: expression EOF;

expression: binaryExpression;

binaryExpression
    : binaryExpression 'and' binaryExpression
    | binaryExpression 'or' binaryExpression
    | quantifier
    | '(' expression ')'
    | OPERAND
;

quantifier
    : 'no' ID 'in' ID 'satisfies' expression
;

OPERAND: 'true' | 'false';
ID: [a-z]+;
WS: (' ' | '\r' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

If you try to parse the following expression, you'll notice that, although the parse correctly recognizes the input, it reports an ambiguity:

```
true or false and no x in y satisfies true or false
```

[image: Ambiguity]

The error reporting works as expected (more about this later):

[image: Error recovery]

```
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '1'
line 1:2 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'no', OPERAND}
```

I'm looking for some way to explicitly tell the parser that the `quantifier` should be greedy: everything on the right-hand side should be consumed unambiguously until the end of the expression.

I tried to refactor the rules to allow the `quantifier` only on the RHS of binary expressions. Although it worked, the error recovery mechanism becomes unable to recognize most expressions:

```
grammar Example;

root: expression EOF;

expression: quantifier | booleanExpression;

quantifier
    : 'no' ID 'in' ID 'satisfies' expression
;

booleanExpression
    : orExpression ('or' (quantifier | andQuantifier))?
    | andQuantifier
;

andQuantifier: andExpression 'and' quantifier;

orExpression
    : orExpression 'or' orExpression
    | andExpression
;

andExpression
    : andExpression 'and' andExpression
    | '(' expression ')'
    | OPERAND
;

OPERAND: 'true' | 'false';
ID: [a-z]+;
WS: (' ' | '\r' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

As you can see, the problem is gone:
[image: Unambiguous parse tree]

But it came at the cost of more complex grammar and unable to recognize wrong inputs like `(1`:

[image: Error recovery]

```
line 1:1 token recognition error at: '1'
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input '('
```

Does anyone else have any other idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Two questions: first, could you please include your failed refactoring attempt? The solution undoubtedly involves some kind of refactoring so it would be good to know why the one you tried failed. (I can't figure out how "it worked" coexists with "unable to recognize most expressions".) Second, what are your expectations for operator precedence?

Comment: Hi @rici! I've edited the question to include my failed attempts. About the precedence, it's the usual: conjunctions have higher priority than disjunctions, as expressed in the grammar I gave.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on your goal to "trailing expressions without enclosing symbols" (I'm not really following what you're trying to accomplish)?

Comment: Also, I was not able to get ambiguity errors in any combination of input you provided.  What version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: The second example error message is a result of the ```expression: quantifier | booleanExpression;``` rule, so it attempts to match a quantifier and, when it fails, tries to recognize a boolean and fails.  (Also, I would expect both grammars to fail to recognize "(1" as it is not valid in your grammar, and both examples give the appropriate error for the grammar used on them.

Comment: @MikeCargal, I'm using  4.7.2. Well, I'm trying to avoid https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0dyb.png, so my goal is to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfFh2.png.

Yeah, I understand why the error reporting is like that, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I know the input is wrong, and it should be, as it's what I'm trying to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I'd do it, using Antlr4's built-in algorithm for resolving ambiguity with precedence (since the grammar is certainly ambiguous). In order to get the precedence algorithm to work, it's useful to think of a qualification as a unary operator with low precedence, which is why `quantifier` below is just the "operator" and not the full expression. Presumably in a real grammar you would have other quantifiers, and very likely unary operators with higher precedence like `not`.

```
grammar Example;

root: expression EOF;

expression
    : expression 'and' expression
    | expression 'or' expression
    | quantifier expression
    | operand
    | '(' expression ')'
;

quantifier
    : 'no' ID 'in' ID 'satisfies'
;

operand: BOOLEAN | ID;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
ID: [a-zA-Z]+;
WHITE_SPACE: (' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

This isn't quite the same as the example in your post because you modified a few minor details from the first version of the question. But I think it's indicative.

For obvious reasons I couldn't try it with `(1` (I suppose that input corresponds to yet a different version where integers are OPERANDs), but with `(true` it gave me what looks like the error report you are seeking. I'm not really an ANTLR4 expert so I don't know how to predict the details of error recovery.

Comment: After the back and forth on my answer, I believe that what @MarcosPassos is looking for is that the boolean expression immediately before the ```'no' ID 'in' ID 'satisfies'```. (ie. ```quantifier```) is associated with the ```quantifier``` rather than the previous content).  This doesn't accomplish that.  By "Greedy" it appears that he wants the quantifier to be "greedy" of the prior content (normally, I think of "greedy" as a tendency to keep pulling in content that follows).  If my understanding is correct, then he needs the ```quantifier``` to be right associative (like exponentiation).

Comment: @Mike: Well, that's not what I got from the question. So it's cool. They have alternatives. Hopefully, one of them is what is being sought and they will eventually get around to either indicating which or better clarifying the needs.

Comment: Thank you @rici! It did the job!

Answer (score -1):

OK, after a lot of back and forth here, I think I finally get that what you're looking for is associativity.  Try:

```
grammar Example;

root: expression EOF;

expression
    : '(' expression ')'                            # parenExpr
    | <assoc=right>expression (AND | OR) quantifier # quantifierExpr
    | expression AND expression                     # andExpr
    | expression OR expression                      # orExpr
    | OPERAND                                       # operandExpr
;

quantifier
    :  'no' ID 'in' ID 'satisfies' expression
;

AND: 'and';
OR: 'or';
OPERAND: 'true' | 'false';
ID: [a-z]+;
WS: (' ' | '\r' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

(I took the liberty of adding labels to your alternatives and simplifying the expression rule.). The labels will come in very handy in your code as you need to deal with each alternative individually.  Labels will give you separate functions to override in your listeners/visitors (along with Context classes specific to that alternative)

```
true and false or false and no x in y satisfies true or false
```

[image]

```
true and false or false or no x in y satisfies true or false
```

[image]

```
true and false or false and no x in y satisfies true or false
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mike! Thank you for trying to help, but it doesn't fix the problem. The parser still reports ambiguous trees, see:
https://ibb.co/h2J3MgZ

Comment: I'm missing your point somehow.  Your image is of two different expressions and both look to me to have a non-ambiguous (and correct, for their input) parseTree.  I guess I need a clearer example that clearly points out what you're interpreting as ambiguity.  (Are you getting an ambiguity error from ANTLR, or do you feel that the results are ambiguous?  If you think the results are ambiguous, I guess I need that clarified, because I'm not seeing it (may just em being "dense")

Comment: The parser can recognize, but it's choosing one of the possible representations. My goal is to explicitly tell the parser that only one of the possible alternatives is valid. The screenshot I've shared comes from the ANTLR plugin for Intellij, showing that there are multiple interpretations at `and no x in y satisfies true or false`. So the parser still can't understand that just one of them is valid (the right side of the screenshot).

Comment: So is it always an AND, (i.e. ```and no x in y satisfies ...```, but never ```or no x in y satisfies...```)?    If I'm starting to follow, it seems that the ```and``` is really part of what you're calling a trailing expression.  Am I "getting it"? (eh, still don't think I'm getting it. The right hand side in both of your diagrams (the trailing expression) is the same, so still not seeing the difference. The are both giving the same subtree of ```and no x in y satisfies true or false``` (from what I see)

Comment: I'll try again :). There are two possible trees from the input `true and false or false and no x in y satisfies true or false` for the parser. The first one is  `(true and false) or (false and no x in y satisfies true or false)` that's exactly what I want. The second one is `((true and false) or false) and (no x in y satisfies true or false)` that's wrong. You can ignore the parenthesis; it's just to help me make explicit the different interpretations. I need to tell the parser that the first is the only valid way to interpret that expression.

Comment: @Marcos: If `quantifier` weren't in some sense greedy (although I'm not sure that's the right term), you could also get `(true and false) or (false and no x in y satisifies true) or false`. :-) The difference between the two parses you show is operator precedence.

Comment: Do you have an example that shows this happening?  I only get one example parse tree and it's the one that you want.  I can't make it give me ```(true and false) or (false and no x in y satisifies true) or false```.  The ```expression``` at the end of you ```quantifier``` rule prevents ```(true and false) or (false and no x in y satisifies true) or false``` from ever being the interpretation.  it is greedy in the sense you're talking about.  The only way, what you're describing could happen is if what follows 'satisfies' fails to be an expression, then the higher rule would continue to try.

Comment: The example is this one, and that's exactly what I'm getting both in 4.7 and 4.9.

Comment: I'mm seeing it now.  Let me look at it some more...

Comment: Wait, do you want ```(true and false) or (false and no x in y satisfies true or false)``` (as you said 4 comments previous), or ```(true and false) or (false and no x in y satisifies true) or false``` as you said in your last comment.  I can get the former, but the latter would be, um, tricky unless you want to limit the ```expression``` in ```quantifier```

Comment: @Mike: that last (erroneous) parse comes from *my* comment, not Marcos'

Comment: Oh Jeez... didn't realize a third person had entered discussion.  My bad.

Comment: @MarcosPassos I've updated my answer so that it gives the tree you're desiring for the example you've given.  I'm not sure we're hitting what you're shooting for, because of how we're playing with precedence.  I suspect the solution will be in deciding what the correct precedence is between ```and```, ```or```, ```quantifier```

Comment: Ignore answer temporarily... still working on it... current content is broken

Comment: @MarcosPassos. OK, modified answer again.  I *think* this is what you're looking for.  (At least I *really* hope so :) )

Comment: @MarcosPassos just checking in, rather curious as to whether this solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Mike! I still got ambiguity from your answer. Much appreciated all the help! :)

Comment: Want to share what ambiguity you’re still getting?  (Is ANTLR reporting an ambiguity error, or is there some other input resolving to a parse tree you’re not expecting?). So far I haven’t seen anything that’s what we typically call an ambiguity, just an expectation of the parse tree structure that doesn’t match what you’re looking for.  What is the input you’re using, and your expected structure?

Comment: I am interested in understanding what your needing (there's obviously a lot talking past each other particularly in the use of terminology, but that's just something to work through).  I'm always a bit curious how people are trying to use ANTLR and the problems their trying to solve.  It's an interesting challenge to find solutions to things challenging ANTLR users.  (I thought all the inputs I had matched your expectations; are we still talking past each other?)

Comment: sorry,I missed that you had accepted Rici's answer... Guess I need to go take a look at what I misunderstood.  Good Luck

Comment: mike: Antlr doesn't report ambiguities by default; it just resolves them according to some heuristics. But you can ask it to identify them. If you're using `grun` (TestRig), you need to provide the `--diagnostics` command-line argument. According to the Antlr book (in Chapter 9, Error reporting), you do this by getting the parser to use a DiagnosticErrorListener, and then turn on `LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION` so that it reports all ambiguities. (Apparently, "all ambiguities" does not include ambiguities resolved with precedence rules.)

Comment: I guess the intellij tool does something like that. I've never used it, so I don't really know.

Comment: @rici Thanks!  all these years using ANTLR and I missed the -diagnostics flag.  I generally use the command line grun myself, and have just set up IntelliJ and plugin to get familiar with it.  TBH, I worked a long time on my own language, so after bootstrapping the whole thing, never had to do much with gun, etc.  Trying to answer ANTLR questions has exposed me to corners I never had to deal with in my language.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @rici I see the ambiguity messages in the run output as well as the diagnostics in IntelliJ tool now.  That probably would have prevented a LOT of misunderstanding.  Just couldn't see what "ambiguities" Marcos was referring to.  It looks like it identifies them "disagnostically", but goes ahead and resolves the ambiguity when you parse.... interesting

Comment: @Mike: It detects some of them automatically and doesn't do the extra work necessary to detect others. But in the case of the ones it does detect, the default ErrorListener deliberately ignores them, because the ANTLR philosophy is that the user of a parser shouldn't be informed of what is almost certainly a bug in the grammar. As I said, it's all explained in the ANTLR book except for the part which I would have found most useful, which is how, exactly, the parser decides whether an ambiguity is an ambiguity, as opposed to the normal working of declared precedence.

Comment: @rici guess I need to re-read a chapter :)   Maybe about time to re-read the book, now that I've been caught up in answering questions.  It is certainly broadening my understanding of ANTLR compared to what I had to do for my own language.  Thanks for the pointer.